# Stop socks5 (ss5) to logging in start up

Tags: socks

I want to stop ss5 to logging into any file in the server. i saw this command:

```
ss5 -m
```

But i  want to find a solution to change any config file, so that it effect when the server start or restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't test yet

```
 SS5_LOG_FILE
 sets absolute pathname of ss5 log file
```

e.g:

```
set SS5_LOG_FILE /dev/null
```

or

Edit /etc/sysconfig/ss5 and add following line:

```
SS5_OPTS=" -m"
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know what the `/dev/null` path is, before.